# Proving that a closed plane in $\mathbb R^3$ has a point in the plane closest to an arbitrary point outside the plane

Tags: calculus, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A= \{\ x \in \mathbb R^3: |x_1| + 2|x_2| +|x_3|^3 = 1\ \}$ and let $P \in \mathbb R^3\setminus A$.
Show that there exists a point $y \in A$ that is closest to $P$ among all points in $A$. Assume $ \mathbb R^3$ has the euclidean metric

```
I obviously want to do this by contradiction,
```

I was able to show that a function $f:A \to  P$ (all points $p$ in $\Bbb R^3\setminus A$) is continuous
Likewise I was able to show that $A$ is totally bounded. I know that if I can show that $A$ is closed, then it is compact and that my function  $f$ attains a max and min. Can someone please help show that $A$ is closed!

Comment: Are you trying to prove existence or uniqueness (or both)?  Uniqueness isn't true...if you take, say, $p=(0,0,0)$ then whatever $y$ is we can change the signs of the non-zero terms to get another point on $A$ which is the same distance to $p$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is closed because it is the preimage of the closed set $\{1\}$ under the continuous map $(x,y,z)\mapsto |x|+2|y|+|z|^3$.